# Laravel location of created files

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm attempting to modify a text file stored on the server using Larvel's `File::put(filelocation,filecontents)`

but I can't figure out what location this is relative to on the server. If I have a file "somestuff.json" within my LaravelApp/public folder, what location string do I use for a parameter to File::put() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File name for `File::methods()` is not relative you have to give the full file path:

```
File::put('/var/www/LaravelApp/public/somestuff.json', $filecontents);
```

But Laravel has some helpers to help you with this:

```
File::put(public_path().'/somestuff.json', $filecontents);
```

Also:

```
base_path(); // the base of your application LaravelApp/

app_path(); // Your LaravelApp/app
```

They are all in the file `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php`.

Comment: perfect, Laravel always has just what I'm looking for